# Homomorphic encryption - Why does addition not imply multiplication?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

As far as I know:

There are some **partially homomorphic encryption** (PHE) systems that support either addition *or* multiplication.

A **fully homomorphic encryption** (FHE) system can do addition as well as multiplication and thus supports arbitrary computation on ciphertexts.

My question is (disregarding computational efficiency):

Why does a PHE-system that allows addition on ciphertext not directly imply that it also can do multiplication, since

$$a \times b$$

is the same as

$$\underbrace{a + a + \cdots + a}_{b\text{ times}}?$$

Are there some computations that are only possible with a direct multiplication instead of a continuous addition?

Comment: What you do is multiplication by a **constant** value $b$. Indeed you can do it, and also you can use double-and-add to perform multiplication by $b$ in $\log{b}$ additions. However, you can not multiply by **encrypted** value $b$ publicly (without knowing the secret key), and that is what FHE is expected to provide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least two problems;

1. The $b$-times addition leaks the $b$. A semi-honest observer can see that you add the $a$ by $b$ times. However, in FHE, the $b$ is also encrypted with semantically secure that leaks no information. The only information available to the observer is the circuit.
2. In FHE, the $b$ is coming (or may come) from another result, which means that $b$ is also encrypted. In additive PHE, you cannot multiply by $b$ without decryption.

You can look at some example of FHE circuits from this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63781/representing-a-function-as-fhe-circuit/63783#63783) to see that some of them are not even possible with additive PHE.

Comment: Why do you care about "leakage" in the first place?

Comment: @Hyperflame It is writing style, keep the important ones lastly! In Cryptanalysis every leak is important.

Comment: I think the FHE notion does not care about leakage of computations. Having a gate 'multiply by 10' or 'multiply by 123' in homomorphic encryption setting is not a problem at all (and as the topic suggests, PHE implies it).

Answer (score 5):

$b$ is encrypted and therefore unknown to the machine doing the multiplication. So, you cannot just "add $b$ times".

One thing you may be tempted to think is just subtract 1 from the encrypted $b$ and stop when $b$ is zero. For a semantically secure homomorphic cipher, this is impossible. If your homomorphic cipher is not semantically secure, it can easily be broken.

Comment: Also: for any ciphertext that is larger than 128 bits in size, it would take an obscenely long amount of time to do the subtract-by-1-until-0 method, even if it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, but I wanted to note that:

If you can add ciphertexts together, then you can multiply them by a *plaintext* value, because of the reason you described in your question.

Similarly, if you can multiply ciphertexts together, then you can exponentiate them by a plaintext value as well.

So if you distribute two ciphertexts $c_0, c_1$ and your algorithm supports only the ability to add ciphertexts together, then it is not possible to meaningfully evaluate $c_0 c_1$, but it is possible for anyone to meaningfully evaluate $c_0p_0$.