# How to implement division operation on ciphertext by using HElib or SEAL?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

HElib has no general purpose API for number operations such as comparison or division. How can we implement division operation on ciphertext？How to encrypt floating numbers of any length in homomorphism and add, subtract, multiply and divide them？

Comment: There is no general API since you have to handle many parameters, all together. Comparison, see here [Representing a function as FHE circuit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63783/18298), for division consider the easiest division as possible that requires low multiplicative depth. Floating, use the fixed point representation?

Comment: Please forgive me not to express myself clearly, it means the plaintext is floating-point. And how can I understand the meaning of the easiest division?

Comment: Yes, I got it, floating-point. Low multiplicative depth?

Comment: But how do I construct a division between ciphertext? by using binary or design a new operation?