# How is it that homomorphic encryption can encrypt program code and run it without decryption?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

In my journey of interest in the world of homomorphic encryption has led me to a concept floating around the internet where they describe homomorphic encryption being used with "mobile agents", which in and of itself a fascinating subject, but I digress...

Specifically from one paper...

> Homomorphic  encryption  [is] a  technique  in  which  the encrypted  mobile  codes can  be  executed  directly  on  different platforms  without  decryption.

I think this could easily be used in blockchains employing zero knowledge proofs for anonymity and security, such as ZCash, that wish to implement "smart contracts" without any inputs, outputs, or code being revealed, extending privacy not just for transactions, but also "smart contract" code and possibly function. "Smart contracts" seem to me kind of like a mobile agent. Anyways...

How is this even possible? How would/does it work?

Edit : I removed the link to the paper in question because it was stated as a "nonsense paper".

Comment: This is one of countless nonsense papers. Quick, burninate any copy!

Comment: Here some [FHE circuits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63783/18298) that may help you understand this GREAT subject. I think this answer is even can be a better article than your nonsense paper.

Comment: Encrypt -> send -> Eval the circuite -> get back -> decrypt.